# Could not open localhost:9000/sonar/ - ubuntu server 16.04.3

Tags: java

0
down vote
favorite

After Sonarqube installation localhost i.e 192.168.0.111:9000/sonar/ does not display any page. Any feedback will be a great help.

Below is the log output.

root@storage:/opt/sonar/logs# ls -ltr
total 116
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42640 Jan 7 18:12 es.2018-01-07.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5330 Jan 8 16:39 es.2018-01-08.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21320 Jan 9 16:42 es.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 30319 Jan 9 16:42 sonar.log
root@storage:/opt/sonar/logs#

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dh60U8z5NZNBxU6U2hAoEZ9sjsSsdpFm/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iFc5ibZRtAe8TtggI0gb87oJxv_Wtqpo/view?usp=sharing

NMAP Output:

root@storage:/opt/sonar/logs# nmap -v -p 9000 192.168.0.227

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-01-09 16:54 +0545 
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 16:54
Scanning storage.bsaitechnosales.com (192.168.0.227) [1 port] 
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 16:54, 0.22s elapsed (1 total ports)
Nmap scan report for storage.example.com (192.168.0.227) Host is up (0.000041s latency). PORT STATE SERVICE 9000/tcp closed cslistener

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.32 seconds
Raw packets sent: 1 (44B) | Rcvd: 2 (84B)

ES LOG OUTPUT:

2018.01.09 09:21:25 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Bootstrap]
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:106) ~[ elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3] at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:195) ~[elasticsearc h-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3] at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:342) [elasticsearch- 5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]

SONAR.LOG Output

root@storage:/opt/sonar/logs# more sonar.log
Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

2018.01.07 15:23:08 INFO app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory
/opt/sonar/temp
2018.01.07 15:23:08 INFO app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.
1:9001
2018.01.07 15:23:08 INFO app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ip
cIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonar/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonar/elasticsearc
h/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/opt/sonar/temp/conf/es
2018.01.07 15:23:08 INFO app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up a
nd running
2018.01.07 15:23:08 INFO app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.01.07 15:23:08 INFO app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.tr
ansport.Netty4Plugin]
2018.01.07 15:23:08 WARN app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit
value [es]: 1
2018.01.07 15:23:08 INFO app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2018.01.07 15:23:08 INFO app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
Wrapper Stopped

Answer (score 0):

Your sonar is failing because elasticsearch won't start:

```
2018.01.07 15:23:08 INFO app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
...
2018.01.07 15:23:08 WARN app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2018.01.07 15:23:08 INFO app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2018.01.07 15:23:08 INFO app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped 
Wrapper Stopped
```

And elasticsearch is failing to start because it is designed to stop if you attempt to run it as root:

```
2018.01.09 09:21:25 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Bootstrap] Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
at [stack trace is irrelevant in this case]
```

Running Sonarqube, Elasticsearch or any major Java application as root is generally a bad idea. Set up an appropriate user account for the application, and filesystem permissions to satisfy the application's requirements.

Don't be seduced into thinking "I'll install as root and adjust it later": it will be much **easier** to set up the account and the application installation directory before the application is installed, and then let the application's own installer create any necessary sub-directories and assign them permissions as required automatically.

Comment: I tried reinstalling elasticsearch from the new user and below is what i have got. What is the solution steps ?

    bsaitechnosales@storage:~/Downloads$ sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
    Starting elasticsearch: /etc/init.d/elasticsearch: line 108: daemon:
    command not found

Comment: Try `sudo -i /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start`. The `-i` option tells `sudo` to perform full environment replacement, rather than preserving e.g. your existing `$HOME` or `$PATH`.